# How to write the formatted matrix in a lines with fortran77?

Tags: fortran, output, fortran77

Suppose I have the matrix c(i,j). I want to write it on the screen on oldest Fortran77 language with three signs after comma. I write

```
         do i=1,N
         write(*,"(F8.3)") ( c(i,j), j=1,N )
         end do
```

but the output is in the form

c(1,1)

c(1,2)

...

c(1,10) c(2,1)

c(2,2)

...

Finally, I may simply write

```
         do i=1,N
         write(*,*) ( c(i,j), j=1,N )
         end do
```

and then the output is like the matrix, but, of course, it is not formatted.

How to get the correct output in Fortran77?

An edit. It seems that one of solutions is to write

```
   do i=1, N
   do j=1, N
    write(*,'(F9.3,A,$)') c(i,j), ' '
   end do
    write(*,*) ' '
   end do
```

Comment: The `$` you have added here is technically nonstandard I believe and can be replaced with, `advance='no'` in more modern fortran (e.g. `write(*,'(F9.3,A)',advance='no') c(i,j), " "`).

Comment: Note, that your solution is NOT Fortran 77. The question is, why are you asking for Fortran 77? You have to dig deep to find F77 only compilers still around. Your code snippets definitely are not F77, thus it is not quite clear what you are asking for.

Comment: @haraldkl : this is not true, since I just ran it by using mpif77 compiler.

Comment: It's entirely possible that `mpif77` is actually pointing at a fortran 90 (and onwards) compatible compiler however. Try running `mpif77 --version` to see what compiler it's actually using "under the hood"

Comment: @d_1999 : it writes: "GNU Fortran (GCC) 5.2.0".

Comment: This is a relatively modern version of `gfortran` which will have quite complete support for many fortran versions from fortran77 up to fortran 2008, so you should be able to use most modern language features (and avoid the old hacks).

Comment: @d_1999: hmm, very interesting. Thank You again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format only specifies a single float but you actually want to write `N` per line.

A fairly general solution for this simple case would be something like

```
  program temp
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: N=3
  real, dimension(N,N) :: c
  integer :: i,j
  character(len=20) :: exFmt
  c = 1.0
  write(exFmt,'("(",I0,"(F8.3))")') N
  do i=1,N
     write(*,exFmt) (c(i,j), j=1,N)
  end do
  end program
```

This will make `exFmt` be `'(3(F8.3))'`, which specifies printing three floats (note you probably really want `'(3(F8.3," "))'` to explicitly include some spacing).

Note some compilers will allow for `exFmt` to be just `'(*(F8.3))'`. This is part of the fortran 2008 specification so may not be provided by all compilers you have access to. See [here](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Fortran+2008+status) for a summary of compiler support (see *Unlimited format item*, thanks to HighPerformanceMark for this)

Finally an easy bodge is to use a format statment like `'(1000(F8.3))'` where 1000 is larger than you will ever need.